# Integration of C#, F#, IronPython and IronRuby

Tags: c#, .net, f#, ironpython, ironruby

I was told that the assembly files made from C# and F# source is interoperable as they are compiled into .NET assembly.

- Q1 : Does that mean that C# can call F# functions just like they are C# functions?
- Q2 : How about the IronPython and IronRuby? I don't see any assembly dll from the IronPython/IronRuby.
- Q3 : Is there any easy way to use IronPython/IronRuby functions from C# or F#?

Any example code would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Yes. Using a simple example, in F#, I can invoke the main method of a C# console app:

```
open SampleApp

SampleApp.Program.Main([| "Hello"; "World" |])
```

2) For the DLR, I think things are a bit different. I believe this is how you would execute Python (for example);

```
ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
ScriptSource script = engine.CreateScriptFromSourceFile("myPythonScript.py");
ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();

script.Execute(scope);
```

My syntax may be off a bit - but you should be able to get the gist.

3) You need to download some special DLR DLLs - and then reference them in your C# / F# application in order to be interoperable. They should be available from the Microsoft DLR site.

Answer (score 3):

> I was told that the assembly files
>   made from C# and F# source is
>   interoperable as they are compiled
>   into .NET assembly.

Yes, you can reference an F# assembly in a C# one. The F# objects etc will function like C# ones when you reference them.

You can access IronPython/Ruby code in C# too, although it's a little different than just referencing an assembly.  Here is an example:

http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/573_First_Look_at_the_IronRuby.aspx

Answer (score 2):

> Q3: Is there any easy way to use IronPython/IronRuby functions from C# or F#?

You might have a look at [Embedding IronPython into a C# application](http://blog.peterlesliemorris.com/archive/2010/05/19/embedding-ironpython-into-a-c-application.aspx)

Basically, what it does (simplified code):

```
var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
var scriptSource = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(@"
def foo(s):
  print s", SourceCodeKind.Statements);

var scope = engine.CreateScope();
scriptSource.Execute(scope);

//Get a reference to the function
Func<string, decimal> foo = scope.GetVariable<Func<string, decimal>>("foo");

//Execute it
Console.WriteLine(foo("a"));
```